# Kotlin hierarchy: Storing child class in parent var

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism, hierarchy

Having a parent class named `Shading`, which is abstract and a child class named `GradientShading`, in Java it was so easy to store a child object into a variable of the parent type:

```
Shading act=null;
act=new GradienShading();
```

In kotlin I don't know how to do it, because this gives compilation error:

```
lateinit var act: Shading
act = GradienShading()
```

> Type mismatch. Required: Shading Found: GradienShading

How can I achieve this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you've not set up the type hierarchy correctly. Are you sure `Shading` in fact is a supertype of `GradientShading`?
The following compiles just fine on my machine.

```kotlin
open class Shading
class GradientShading: Shading()

class Example {
    lateinit var act: Shading
    
    fun test() {
        act = GradientShading()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, finally I was importing a wrong class when doing the extension of GradientShading, because I got two classes with the same name, but one with java and other with kotlin, in this test project. My fault, thank you very much Endzeit.